# Thickbox firefox problems

Tags: jquery, firefox, thickbox

In firefox, if the user clicks the below link before the page loads, it opens in a new window instead of in the thickbox dialog. Any way to prevent this?

I cannot make this happen on IE/safari

Thickbox works by setting a class "thickbox" on a link:

```
<a href="http://someurl.com" class="thickbox none new" title="Open">Open</a>
```

Then in thickbox

```
//on page load call tb_init
$(document).ready(function(){   
    tb_init('a.thickbox, area.thickbox, input.thickbox');//pass where to apply thickbox
    imgLoader = new Image();// preload image
    imgLoader.src = tb_pathToImage;
});
```

Comment: Can you post some code for us to look at?

Comment: Just as a caveat, Thickbox has been officially off life support for over a year and a half now ...  it may be time to look for an alternative plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are loading the various script resources in the correct order. For example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        tb_init(...);
        // etc
    });
</script>
```

This can be in either the `<head>` or preferably, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

As Pointy, err, pointed out, Thickbox is no longer under active development. You might consider one of the following alternatives

- [ColorBox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)
- [DOMWindow](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html) from the same author as Thickbox
- [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm not where I can try this, and I'm not an expert at jQuery, so be forewarned that your mileage may vary with this answer.

Have you tried putting the initialization in $(document).load() instead of $(document).ready()?  If I'm reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) right, ready() gets invoked after the DOM is ready but not necessarily before assets such as other scripts are loaded.  I don't know if that's a solution, but it might be something to try.